# Sending an event object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Whenever an event causes JavaScript code to run an event object named event is created.

1. Does the keyword "event" represent all types of events (for example mouse events, keyboard events etc..)?
2. more importantly, how exactly does this following example work?

   ```
   onmousemove="myFunction(event)"
   ```

Here is the full example of the use of the keyword "event":
http://jsbin.com/AcanusA/10/edit

Comment: there are many tutorials on web explain how javascript work..
i suggest you this one: http://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/JavaScript-Events/140780-2.html

Comment: Note that inlining the Javascript in HTML is bad practice and violates  the [Separation of Concerncs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

Answer (score 0):

`event` is simply a variable name, it's not a [keyword](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6.1.1).

> Does the keyword "event" represent all types of events (for example mouse events, keyboard events etc..) ?

Yes. But see below for more information.

> more importantly, how exactly does this following example work ?

I assume you talk about inline event handlers, the ones you put in HTML:

```
<div onmousemove="myFunction(event)"></div>
```

When the HTML is parsed into a DOM element, a function is created, with the body being the value of the attribute and assigned to corresponding DOM property. We can [easily proof this with](http://jsfiddle.net/9xLWn/)

```
console.log(document.querySelector('div').onmousemove.toString())
```

which shows (in Chrome)

```
function onmousemove(event) {
    myFunction(event)
}
```

As you can see, that funciton has a parameter called `event`. In IE and Chrome there is also the special global variable `window.event`.

In all other cases though, the variable name `event` has no specific significance. It's just a typical name to choose for the event object.  You could use a different variable name if you assign the event handler directly to the DOM element:

```
myDiv.onclick = function(foobar) {
    myFunction(foobar);
};
```

---

To learn more about event handling, have a look at these excellent articles: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: that's got a bit confusing for me..so if I got you right you mean that if I handle the event in JavaScript I can give the function parameter(which is the event itself that was generated) any name and if it's in the html code the default name of the function parameter is event?

Comment: In both cases the event is handled in JS, but you are creating the event handler differently. But yes, that's basically what I was saying.